# eBay API: revising html description

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to revise items' html description part (the seller's custom info at the bottom of eBay item page).
I checked `GetItem` and `ReviseItem` and couldn't find any of description info.
Actually there is a description field, but it's just a text description of an item.

How do I change the custom HTML part of an item?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Never mind!

I need to pass DetailLevel => 'ReturnAll' to get the html description.